# Two formulas in one cell, if result >5, then "URGENT", if not, result of formula #1

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, nested, formula

Im trying to get a formula where if the output of another formula in the same cell is over 5, then type "URGENT". If the value is LESS THAN 5, then output the result in number format

In cell A1, I have: =NOW()

In column U, theres a data validation of "Created & Linked, Pending, See Notes"

In cell w4: =if(U4="Created & Linked!",$A$1-E4,"")
*(If the cell in column U says "created & linked" then subtract todays date from the date manually entered in cell e4)*

I want to replace the contents of cell w4 to say URGENT (instead of a number) ONLY IF the result of '=if(U4="Created & Linked!",$A$1-E4,"")' is MORE THAN 5

I dont know if a formula is best for this or conditional formatting, ive tried a few options but cannot get w4 to say URGENT if the value of =if(U4="Created & Linked!",$A$1-E4,"") is MORE than 5. Usually nothing happens and i just get the result of the formula in number format, so right now it says 6, instead of saying URGENT.

**Basically... how can i combine:**

=if(U4="Created & Linked!",$A$1-E4,"")
*(result should be either a number or a blank space)*

WITH:

=if(w4>5,"URGENT","")
*(result should be if over 5, then type URGENT, if less than 5, show result of =if(U4="Created & Linked!",$A$1-E4,""))*

Comment: `=if(w4>5,"URGENT",if(U4="Created & Linked!",$A$1-E4,""))`

Comment: Hey scott - thanks so much for getting back to me. 

Can you explain the logic of this formula to me? 

Its not working correctly, but it did show the logic in my question was flawed. 

My new logic... 

If:  v4= "created" // this is a data validation

then: x4 = (a1-f4)  // a1= current date // f1 = date of last action
**If v4<> "Created", "" //if v4 does not say created, do nothing

If: x4=>6 //number of days between cell v4 saying "Created" and F4

then: type "Check"

If: x4=<6 // its been less than 6 days since v4 said "Created"

then: x4 = (a1-f4)